# Hide field in inspector in one class but not the other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three classes, class `A` is abstract and class `B` and `C` extend it.

Is there a way for me to hide the property in class `A` when I place `C` on a game object, and show it when I place class `B` on a game object?

```
public abstract class A : MonoBehaviour {
    public float myFloat = 0f;
}

public class B : A {
    // Show myFloat in inspector
}

public class C : A {
    // Do not show myFloat in inspector
}
```

The only other way I can think of is to create my own Editor class for the two classes, but I would like to avoid that if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Custom Inspectors: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/building-custom-inspector. This allows you to customize the Inspector for any types you like.

This will definately work, though it may be cumbersome if you have many members in your type. Other than this I don't see much chance.

Comment: This is what I decided to do.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [[HideInInspector]](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html), you need to apply the attribute where the variable is defined.

Example referenced in the Unity3d docs site (which provides very little help...):

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public int p = 5;
}
```

Comment: That will hide it in both `B` and `C` though

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes, as far as I understand. It's the only way I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean whether you could hide the variable from the parent (Abstract) class in one derived class, and leave it accessible from the other derived class? If I'm right then it can't be done with C# using private/protected inheritance since C# only allows public inheritance.